# HttpEntity content already consumed

Tags: java, entity

I searched about this error and i found it usually happen when you try to GetContent twice or more times, but the thing is, i am not, i have two almost identical methods, one works, the other don't..

Method ParseHor() -Doesn't work

```
public ArrayList<Hor> ParseHor() throws Exception{
    ArrayList<Horario> listHorario = new ArrayList<Horario>();

    HttpGet get = new HttpGet(
            URL1);
    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(get);
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    InputStream is = entity.getContent(); // Create an InputStream with the

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,
            "iso-8859-1"));

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                ...
    }
```

ParseGrades() - Works

```
public ArrayList<Grade> ParseGrades() throws Exception {

    HttpGet get = new HttpGet(
            URL2);
    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(get);
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    InputStream is = entity.getContent(); // Create an InputStream with the

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,
            "iso-8859-1"));

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                ...
       }
```

I tried to call just ParseHor(), but when it gets on the InputStream line, the exception rises with IllegalState - Content already consumed

Comment: Have you tried open your URLs by browser or some other client? Maybe error in the other side?
Also there is misspelling: ParseNotas should be ParseGrades

Comment: The url is openning just fine, actually I tried with the URL from the ParseGrades(), but called on ParseHor() and didn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it, the problem was that the name of the variables were the same, i changed that and worked.